# Is there recommended true type font for search and rescue?

Tags: qgis, font, emergency-services

Has anyone run across a true type font set to use for search and rescue cartography, and/or fire cartography?

This is specifically for Terrain Navigator Pro which isn't really a GIS application but can make use of true type fonts, which could be also used in QGIS which we use to make maps, since TNP doesn't have the same functionality.

Why what we're using is less than ideal: 1) we need to use TNP since it is much better suited for SAR missions than any heavyweight GIS application, and 2) the symbols and system fonts that come with TNP aren't specific enough for our needs.

Comment: Can you try to qualify your question with some more details: "really good" and "higher quality" are subjective terms, leading to opinion based answers (which are out-of-scope, see FAQ). What have you already looked at? Does EMS (see http://emsymbology.org/EMS/docs/EMS_Symbology_v1.0.pdf) have what you need? If not, why not? What do you need in addition, or what are the issues with that set?

Comment: It seems the subjectivity mold has been broken long ago by some of the biggest hit questions on this site such as 'what makes a beautiful map'.  I'm not sure what an objective synonym would be; maybe just striking the words 'really good' would help, and replacing 'higher quality' with 'capable of displaying more detail than Terrain Navigator Pro'.  Anyway - interesting web site, I had not seen that.  Though unless I'm missing something, those aren't truetype fonts, are they?  Terrain Navigator Pro can't use custom graphics at all; only true type fonts.

Comment: Edit the question.

Comment: When asking for something specific (and this sounds *really* specific), it helps to provide details such as an example of why what you're currently using is less than ideal. That being said, the FGDC created a TTF format point symbology for emergency management. You can read about it [here](http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/committee/emprep/download/FEMA-GIS/Point_Symbology_For_EM.02JUN07.sds.pdf). I am not sure where to download it though, but I believe it is now included with ArcGIS. Edit: You can download them [here](http://www.fgdc.gov/HSWG/ref_pages/DownloadSymbols_ref.htm).

Comment: Edits completed.

Comment: Thanks for the link - that looks like a pretty good fit.